# Merging two XML files with XSLT

Tags: xml, merge, xslt-1.0

I've searched for a solution for my problem. I found some similar questions and answers but none of them fitted to my problem.

I'm an XML newbie and never used XSLT before. I have Linux and could use xsltproc or xmllint (or whatever would be best).

The problem is rather easy. I have to XML files with identical layout. At the beginning is a counter for the nodes included in one file. I just need the counters of both files added and then all nodes from both files as a single list. (Sorted would be even better.)

Example:
a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>115</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>9639</uid>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>100</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>4711</uid>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

Result:
out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>215</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>4711</uid>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <uid>9639</uid>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

How can I manage that? I don’t post my XSLTs here because they are not working and that’s because of my limited skills. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. The idea here is that you apply the XSL transformation to document `a.xml`, and pass the path to the `b.xml` file as a parameter.

You will probably want to change the node/s to sort on to something more reasonable.

Note the use of a prefix to address the nodes in your XML sources, since they are all in a namespace.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="doc2" select="'b.xml'" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:Record_Count">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=". + document($doc2)/ns1:List/ns1:publshInformation/ns1:Record_Count" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:List">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|document($doc2)/ns1:List/ns1:Entry">
            <xsl:sort select="ns1:firstName" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```