# Path not found within XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a follow up question. I have copied the original question below.

I made the mentioned changes but it seems that xsltproc doesn't find b.xml though a.xml and b.xml are in the same folder. I call xsltproc right from the same folder. Maybe my call is incorrect. I used

```
xsltproc -v --debug -o output.xml merge3.xsl a.xml
```

where merge3.xsl is your (adapted) example. I know that --debug and -v are not necessary but I wanted to see what xsltproc is doing.

Unfortunately output.xml is an exact copy of a.xml.

What does the "ns1" in an XSLT mean? I wonder if my paths are set correctly. I suppose that ns1 is a parameter of my call. But which one?

Even if I use  full paths to all of the files I only get a copy of a.xml. Where is the mistake?

This is merge3.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="doc2" select="'b.xml'" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:Record_Count">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=". + document($doc2)/ns1:List/ns1:publshInformation/ns1:Record_Count" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:List">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|document($doc2)/ns1:List/ns1:Entry">
            <xsl:sort select="ns1:uid" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This was the original question:

I've searched for a solution for my problem. I found some similar questions and answers but none of them fitted to my problem.

I'm an XML newbie and never used XSLT before. I have Linux and could use xsltproc or xmllint (or whatever would be best).

The problem is rather easy. I have to XML files with identical layout. At the beginning is a counter for the nodes included in one file. I just need the counters of both files added and then all nodes from both files as a single list. (Sorted would be even better.)

Example:
a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>115</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>9639</uid>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>100</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>4711</uid>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

Result:
out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/List.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/17/2014</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>215</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <Entry>
    <uid>4711</uid>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <uid>9639</uid>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
....
  </Entry>
</List>
```

How can I manage that? I don’t post my XSLTs here because they are not working and that’s because of my limited skills. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `ns1` is the declared namespace prefix for the URL *http://tempuri.org/List.xsd*. It strange that it relates to a URI leading to an XSD. Please show the input XML as well.

Comment: Please have a look here for the input XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826786/merging-two-xml-files-with-xslt

Comment: It's better to add it in the same and single post :)

Comment: Done. See question above.

Comment: I have used your provided sample files with xsltproc and the result contains `<Record_Count>215</Record_Count>` so the values are added and there are two `Entry` elements in the output, I am not sure what goes wrong on your system. Double check your files and paths.

Comment: I can't get it running. I don't have any ideas anymore. My system is Linux and the problem seems to be that  the 2nd document isn't found. I tried a relative path, an absolute path. I tried <xsl:param name="doc2" select="'b.xml'" /> aswell as without the ' and just the ": <xsl:param name="doc2" select="b.xml" />. When I copy the path I entered there (absolute path) and paste it behind the view command in the Linux shell I'm viewing the file. So the path is correct. However whatever I do xsltproc either ignores the 2nd file or I get a syntax error if the syntax I tried is invalid.
Any ideas?